# PHP echo POST variable with same name

Tags: php, mysql, post, echo

Ok i have two tables with a left join.  Let call  table one "people" and the second table "dog".  I have left joined the tables by an id:

```
"SELECT * FROM people
      LEFT JOIN dog ON people.PK = dog.fk";
```

My problem is that both tables have a column title "name."  When i echo back out the $_POST['name'] variable it give the same value for both fields I tried

```
echo $_POST['people.name']
echo $_POST['dog.name']
```

but this isn't returning any data so this must be incorrect.  Can someone help me fix my problem without having to change my column names.  Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_POST` superglobal contains data submitted from a form. It does not contain data from database queries. You probably do something like this (pseudocode):

```
$result = database_query (
    "SELECT * FROM people LEFT JOIN dog ON people.PK = dog.fk"
);
```

The data you want is now contained in the variable named `$result`. How you access it will depend on your database access method, but typically you would fetch a row from the result object, perhaps as an associative array.

```
$row = database_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Then the array `$row` would contain your data.

```
echo $row['name'];
```

You might need to alias the column names in the query in order to be able to access the values of both `name` columns.

Comment: You are correct, i was writing this post a hypothetical and just used post not thinking it through.  Yes would be using $row or something like that and will have to alias the columns.  Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Alias the column names and don't use `SELECT *` but specify columns manually:

```
SELECT people.name AS people_name, dog.name AS dog_name
FROM people
LEFT JOIN dog ON people.PK = dog.fk
```

Then you can access the fields through `['people_name']` and `['doc_name']`.
Depending on your table structure and which field you actually need you could also `SELECT table1.*, table2.somecol AS t2_somecol` - that's handy if you need everything from the first table but only a few fields from the second one.

Oh, and you *really* shouldn't put stuff into `$_POST`. It's meant to be populated by PHP with POST data - and data coming from your DB is not really POST data.

Comment: I don't think so. For me it looks like his SQL results are "broken" due to the same field name being used twice and that he - for some reason - stores them in `$_POST`.

Comment: +1 as I was typing this exactly. But I would add backticks to quote the fields.

Comment: No need to use backticks. You only need them if you want to use otherwise-reserved keywords as column/table names and it's better to avoid that for the sake of more readable SQL.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: you clearly have not been in the situation where the mysql people decided to add a few reserved keywords which you happened to use as field names (happened to me from version 3-4 if I recall correctly). Good luck fixing your entire codebase next upgrade...

Comment: I did not consider the possibility that he stores the data in `$_POST`, but I still interpret the question as confusion about what `$_POST` is for. However, I remove my downvote.

Comment: Indeed, but that usually happens with a major version upgrade and in such a case you need to re-test your whole application anyway. And yeah @Hammerite, that downvote is more suited for the question itself ;)

Comment: My downvote is locked in unless the answer is edited. This is despite the fact that you edited your answer in the time since I left the downvote. I am puzzled by this.

Comment: Just edited it after i saw that you might not be able to change the vote. You probably tried to remove it a moment before

Comment: FYI http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html 227 in total, 37 of which are new in 5.0.